# for loop work at multiple directory depth

Tags: bash, for-loop

I have the following for loop in bash:

```
for file in "$1"/*PM.mov ; do 
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -an -f framemd5 "${file}.framemd5.txt"
done
```

I want to adjust it so that it will run on any *PM.mov file in a given directory regardless of the directory depth of that file. Right now the loop only runs on the top level of the directory. How do I change that?

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities:

- Use [`globstar`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) (and `nullglob` while we're at it):

  ```
  shopt -s globstar nullglob
  for file in "$1"/**/*PM.mov ; do 
      ffmpeg -i "$file" -an -f framemd5 "${file}.framemd5.txt"
  done
  ```
- Use `find` *properly* (but the previous one is better, as it's only a minor change to your code):

  ```
  find "$1" -type f -name "*PM.mov" -exec sh -c 'file=$1; ffmpeg -i "$file" -an -f framemd5 "$file.framemd5.txt"' sh {} \;
  ```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why is the `sh -c` necessary? Can't you just have `find` execute `ffmpeg` directly?

Comment: @MikeHolt: Indeed, most versions of `find` will be okay with `find "$1" -type f -name "*PM.mov" -exec ffmpeg -i {} -an -f framemd5 {}.framemd5.txt \;` but [as specified by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html#tag_20_47), _If a utility_name or argument string contains the two characters "{}", but not just the two characters "{}", it is implementation-defined whether find replaces those two characters or uses the string without change._ That's why, to be 100% sure it will work on any POSIX-compliant system, I chose to comply to the spec.

Comment: Good to know. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! @gniourf_gniourf

Answer (score 0):

use the find cmd

```
for file in $(find $1 -name "*PM.mov") ; do 
    ffmpeg -i "$file" -an -f framemd5 "${file}.framemd5.txt"
done
```

Comment: Use the `find` command: yes; but [don't use it that way!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Another option is to use `globstar`: `shopt -s globstar; for file in **/*PM.mov; do ...; done`.

Comment: Doing it this way will cause problems with filenames that contain spaces. Better to pipe or redirect the output of `find` into a `while` loop. Or better still, just use the `find` command's `-exec` option: `find $1 -name "*PM.mov" -exec ffmpeg -i "{}" -an -f framemd5 "{}.framemd5.txt" \;`